# Cygwin rvm error win 7 32-bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cygwin, rvm

### I am getting error in cygwin rvm under Window 7 32-bit:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

**Error running 'make ', please read /home/User/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/make.log**

---

**/home/User/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/make.log**
make
Error: don't know how to make '/configure.ac'

Comment: What is in your log file? "Error running 'make', please read /home/User/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/make.log"

Comment: please stop removing previous content from question, either open new questions or add EDITS, removing content invalidates answers and confuses future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Problem is solved by reinstalling the cygwin with following packages**

```
Vim
git
git-completion
gitk
curl
ruby
sqlite3
libsqlite3_0
libsqlite3-devel
gcc
colorgcc
make
libtool
libncurses-devel
ncurses
openssl
openssl-devel
openssh
zlib
zlib-devel
patch
wget
unzip
```

Now each and every thing working fine. Thanks every body for providing your support.

Answer (score 1):

looks like windows `make` does not support `-j` switch like *nix `make` does, you can separate installation in to two steps to make it working:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm install 1.9.3
```

as you already installed rvm you can run just the second command to install ruby.

---

EDIT01: new error, missing file: `/home/User/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/depcomp`
check if it exists and is readable

other error: `/bin/sh: /home/User/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/missing: Permission denied`

---

EDIT02: new error, this time it looks like some bug in either how yaml is compiled on windows or just the compilation tools used, ensure you have installed autoconf, automake, gcc, libtool, make - and try again.

Comment: make sure you read `/home/User/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/make.log` again as the error inside could change.

Comment: I suspect that the issue isn't missing file, but rather that he doesn't have the appropriate permissions to read the file. The error reported by the script about depcomp not existing is incorrect. It is preceded by `cp: cannot openconfig/depcomp' for reading: Permission denied`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this with sudo? E.g. `sudo rvm install 1.9.3`

I see a few permission denied errors in your logs. The error messages you are getting from the scripts seem to think that there are missing files, but I suspect it's just that the files require root permissions to read or write or execute.

You could also try fixing your permissions, but sudo is probably easier.

**/home/User/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/configure.log is following:**

```
/bin/sh: /home/User/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/missing: Permission denied
configure: WARNING: missing' script is too old or missing
```

...

```
cp: cannot openconfig/depcomp' for reading: Permission denied
./configure: line 3656: ./depcomp: No such file or directory none
```

...

```
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh config/config.sub
```

Comment: I guess Cygwin doesn't have a sudo command. Try running Cygwin as an Administrator. You can right click the shortcut and click "run as administrator."